# Get selected QTreeWidget cells

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

Say I have a treeWidget with 6 rows and 6 columns. I have set the selection behaviour to select individual items as opposed to the entire row. This works as expected and I can select individual cells. My question is how do I query what cells are currently selected?

I've tried using treeWidget.selectedItems(), but this returns a list treeWidgetItems, which from what I can tell, corresponds to the whole row. So if I select several columns in the same row, this command returns a list  containing a single treeWidgetItem. And I can find no way to find out which columns are selected within that treeWidgetItem.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: You could iterate over the tree and call [QTreeWidgetItem::isSelected()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#isSelected) on each item.

Comment: This may work if isSelected() had a parameter for column, but it doesn't. Remember QTreeWidgetItem represents the whole row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use the `QItemSelectionModel` and call the method `selectedIndexes()`

**Reference**: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedIndexes

```
QItemSelectionModel* model = myTreeWidget->selectionModel();
QModelIndexList indexList = model->selectedIndexes();

for(int i = 0; i < indexList.size(); ++i) {
    QTreeWidgetItem* item = myTreeWidget->itemFromIndex( indexList[i] );
    // do something with each item
}
```

Also the individual indexes in the list will contain `.row()` and `.column()` information that may be helpful.

#### Edit

As example of using `.column()` from the index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < indexList.size(); ++i) {
    QTreeWidgetItem* item = myTreeWidget->itemFromIndex( indexList[i] );

    int c = indexList[i].column();
    QVariant d = item.data(c, Qt::DisplayRole);
    d = QVariant( d.toString() + "*" )
    item->setData(c, Qt::DisplayRole, d);    
}
```

Each time this loop runs, the cells selected should add `*` to the end.

**edit:** fixed issue with the call to `item->setData( ... )`